# KVM Command Line Args Similar to Virt-Manager

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I am working on virtualizing a windows 7 image using kvm on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. Here are the specs for my machine:

CPU: Intel i7-2860WM
,8G RAM

I am using an image created with WinImage of a Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit machine.

I am able to create a virtual machine and run it successfully using the "virt-manager" tool. In order for the image to run correctly I must specify the disk bus type as SATA, otherwise when the virtual machine tries to boot I receive a BSOD with an error code of 0x0000007B which pertains to errors initializing the hard disk.

I would like to be able to create/start this virtual machine from the cmd line using kvm instead of using the virt-manager utility. However when I try the following:

```
sudo kvm -hda Win7.vhd
```

The machine boots and immediately goes to a BSOD with an error code of 0x0000007B. I need a way from the command line to specify the virtual machine to use a SATA bus. Or so I need to create a virtual SATA bus and have it boot from the Win7.vhd image? Basically I need to be able to specify SATA as the bus option from the command line, but I have not had any luck with this. Any and all thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's like this:

```
 -device ahci,id=ahci \
 -drive file=a_windows_test_image,if=none,id=drv \
 -device ide-drive,drive=drv,bus=ahci.0
```

However given that you can run the VM already with virt-manager, you can find out the arguments that it is currently using by

```
  ps auwwx | grep kvm
```

Just to make sure you have all needed args - as what you have is a bit sparse; i.e. you've not told the VM how much memory it has, does it have a display etc... so the BSOD is probably more due to that. hth